# Sed issue not replacing special character

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace a character to work with Zenity. This works as expected:

```
echo "& <" | sed 's/&/&amp;/g'
```

But I'm having issues doing the following:

```
echo "<" | sed 's/</&lt;/g'
```

The output becomes this:

```
<lt;
```

I tried doing backslash infront of the special character and that didn't work either, as well as double quoting.

Am I missing something that's super obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Literally found the answer after posting.
backslash is needed before the & symbol, rather than the < which I had tried before posting.

```
echo "<" | sed 's/</\&lt;/g'
```

Works fine now.

Comment: You should explain why you need it: an unescaped `&` is replaced  the whole of the match string, but it worked it the first case because of the fluke that the match string is `&` itself.

Comment: This happens because `&` is special to sed on the replacement side of `s` command. `echo a | sed 's/[a-z]/&&&/'` From `info sed` `Also, the REPLACEMENT can contain unescaped '&' characters which reference the whole matched portion of the pattern space.` The first example worked because you replaced a literal `&` by the special `&` that matched the literal `&`.

Comment: AFH beat me to it